# C# asp.net - Update specific row on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I currently have an asp.net gridview with a checkbox column and button. I am trying to update the database table where the checkbox has been checked.

My SQL table has the following fields

> row_id(int)
>   MagazineCode(varchar)
>   Dimensions(varchar)
>   Obselete(int)

WEBFORM.aspx

```
 <div id="effortGridHolder" style="width: 888px; height: 270px; overflow: auto;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" CellPadding="4"
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%"
            DataKeyNames="MagazineCode" >

            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="MagazineCode"
                    HeaderText="MagazineCode" SortExpression="MagazineCode" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Profile_ID"
                    HeaderText="Profile_ID" SortExpression="Profile_ID" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Dimensions"
                    HeaderText="Dimensions" SortExpression="Dimensions" />

    <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Obselete">
    <itemtemplate>
    <asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect"    runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
    </itemtemplate>
    </asp:templatefield>
            </Columns> 

<asp:Button ID="obselete_btn" OnClick="obselete_submit" runat="server" Text="Update" />
```

The C# code

```
protected void obselete_submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //GET CHECKED VALUES
    foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("cbSelect") as CheckBox);
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                //update 
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationData"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET Obselete = '1' WHERE MagazineCode = '" + tbMagCode_GAD.Value + "'";
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I am able to get the checked values from checkboxes and when the update button is pressed, it is able to update the Obselete and set it to 1.

The current SQL query for this is:

```
"UPDATE table SET Obselete = '1' WHERE MagazineCode = '" + tbMagCode_GAD.Value + "'";
```

But this isnt great as the database table can have the same MagazineCode and will update the Obselete field for all of them.  I have created a new field called `row_id` and want update the table where `row_id = "gridview row clicked"`

Thanks

Comment: Can't you put `row_id` as a column in your gridview? If `row_id` is equal to the gridview row index than you can use `row_id = GridView1.SelectedIndex`.

Comment: should i create a hidden column called row_id

Comment: Yes it solves your problem. Also I suggest you to use variables with `Sql Command Parameters` in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create a unique Id and Id that in grid and update with That ID

Comment: no in database you might  have some unique column right try to add that column in grid and make it invisible so user will not able to see that id, with that id you Update the value

Comment: Yes i have created an extra field in the database called 'row_id'. I see where your coming from, I will give it a go now. cheers